# State if it's an equivalence relation or not

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have the following problem

> Let $X$ be $Z×Z$, i.e. $X$ is the set of all ordered pairs of the form $(x,
>  y)$ with $x, y ∈ Z$. Define the relation $R$ on $X$ as follows: $(x_1, x_2)\mathrel{R}(y_1, y_2)$ if $x_1^2 + x_2^2 = y_1^2 + y_2^2$.

And I have to state whether it's an equivalence relation or not.

I proved that it's reflexive because

$(x_1,x_2)\mathrel{R}(x_1,x_2)$
$x_1^2 + x_2^2=x_1^2 + x_2^2$

It's symmetric

$(x_1,x_2)\mathrel{R}(x_2,x_1)$
$x_1^2 + x_2^2=x_2^2 + x_1^2$

And also transitive

if $(x_1,x_2)\mathrel{R}(y_1,y_2)$ and $(y_1,y_2)\mathrel{R}(z_1,z_2)$ then $(x_1,x_2)\mathrel{R}(z_1,z_2)$

Therefore, it's an equivalence relation,
but I'm nut sure if I have proved it the right way.

Comment: Reflexive is ok.  Symmetric and transitive need some work.  For symmetric, you need to show that if $(x_1,x_2) R (y_1,y_2)$, then $(y_1,y_2) R (x_1,x_2)$.  For transitive, you wrote what you needed to show, but you did not show it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're wrong about the symmetric property. You have to prove:

> if $(x_1,x_2)\mathrel{R}(y_1,y_2)$, then $(y_1,y_2)\mathrel{R}(x_1,x_2)$

This is rather easy, because it just amounts to switching sides in an equality.

You stated right the transitive property, but didn't prove it.

Hint: from the hypotheses we get $x_1^2+x_2^2=y_1^2+y_2^2$ and $y_1^2+y_2^2=z_1^2+z_2^2$. Then …